Does Lying, Except in Court Testimony, Violate the Ninth Commandment?
Am I transgressing the ninth of the 10 Commandments of Moses if I lie, except when giving testimony in court?
In Exodus 20:13 it reads

You shall not bear false witness against your neighbor


Halachapaedia collects the sources and opinions really well: "The opinion of a few poskim is that this issur is talking about a person swearing in Bais Din or if it might cause damage. (According to this lying is permitted in many situations, see below), while most poskim hold there is an issur even if the lying does not fall into the above categories."

@RabbiKaii I don't think that is referring to the 9th commandment, is it?
